# T-Sql - Business Rule for User/Group Rights

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization

I have a couple of similer tables named GroupRights and UserRights.

```
DECLARE @UserRights TABLE (Id INT, RightId INT)

DECLARE @GroupRights TABLE (Id INT, RightId INT)
```

I have a business rule to enforce here that is: when GroupRights have record then it should be selected but if UserRights also have record with same Id then only UserRight's record be selected.

Here I did some code achieve this

```
SELECT * FROM @UserRights U
UNION 
SELECT G.* FROM @GroupRights G
LEFT OUTER JOIN @UserRights U ON G.Id = U.Id
WHERE U.Id IS NULL
```

with help of following insertions

```
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(1, 3)
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(2, 3)
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(3, 3)
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(5, 3)

INSERT INTO @GroupRights VALUES(1, 1)
INSERT INTO @GroupRights VALUES(2, 1)
INSERT INTO @GroupRights VALUES(3, 5)
INSERT INTO @GroupRights VALUES(4, 1)
```

But this involves selecting from User twice (I have already created a CTE in real code, it is simplified version of this). How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

Please check if this solution solves your needs:

```
;With MyCTE as (
    SELECT id,RightId, '0' c
    FROM UserRights U
    UNION 
    SELECT id,RightId, '1' c
    FROM GroupRights G
),
MyCTE2 as (
    SELECT id,RightId,c,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by id order by c) RN
    from MyCTE
)
select id,RightId
from MyCTE2
where RN = 1
```

For the above solution I used the below DDL+DML:

```
CREATE TABLE UserRights (Id INT, RightId INT)
CREATE TABLE GroupRights (Id INT, RightId INT)

INSERT INTO UserRights VALUES(1, 3)
INSERT INTO UserRights VALUES(2, 3)
INSERT INTO UserRights VALUES(3, 3)
INSERT INTO UserRights VALUES(5, 3)
INSERT INTO GroupRights VALUES(1, 1)
INSERT INTO GroupRights VALUES(2, 1)
INSERT INTO GroupRights VALUES(3, 5)
INSERT INTO GroupRights VALUES(4, 1)

select * from GroupRights
select * from UserRights
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check if this helps

DECLARE @UserRights TABLE (Id INT, RightId INT)
DECLARE @GroupRights TABLE (Id INT, RightId INT)

INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(1, 3)
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(2, 3)
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(3, 3)
INSERT INTO @UserRights VALUES(5, 3)

INSERT INTO @GroupRights VALUES(1, 1)
INSERT INTO @GroupRights VALUES(2, 1)
INSERT INTO @GroupRights VALUES(3, 5)
INSERT INTO @GroupRights VALUES(4, 1)

SELECT * FROM @GroupRights
SELECT * FROM @UserRights

;WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT 
 G.ID,
 G.RightID
 FROM
  @GroupRights G 
  ),
 CTE1 AS
 (
   SELECT 
          U.Id,
          U.RightId
   FROM
          @UserRights U
 )
 SELECT 
       CASE WHEN CTE.Id = CTE1.Id THEN CTE1.Id ELSE CTE.Id END AS Id,
       CASe WHEN CTE.Id = CTE1.Id THEN CTE1.RightID ELSE CTE.RightId END AS         RightId
       FROM CTE LEFT JOIN CTE1 ON CTE1.Id = CTE.Id
```